# Django didn't save form to database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

How can I save a form to the database with an image? It all works fine if I comment the line `imagen = modelImageField` so I think there is the problem in `model.py`. All the other parts of the form save to the database. If I comment out the line, no errors show, but the form is not saved to the database. Can anyone help me with this?

This is my View

```
Views.py
class donacion_Form(CreateView):
template_name='App/donacion.html'
model=donacion
fields="__all__"
success_url=reverse_lazy('mi_donacion')
```

This is the form

```
Forms.py
class donacion_Form(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model=donacion
    fields="__all__"
```

This is the Model

```
Model.py
class donacion(models.Model):
nombre=models.CharField(max_length=50)
estados = (
('EC', 'Excelente condicion'),
('BP', 'Buena presentacin'),
('PD', 'Presenta desgaste'),
('MD', 'Muy desgastada'),
)
prendas = (
('TP', 'Tops'),
('BT', 'Bottoms'),
('CZ', 'Calzado'),
('AS', 'Accesorios'),
('CM', 'Chamarras'),
)
generos = (
('MJR', 'Mujer'),
('HMB', 'Hombre'),
('UXA', 'Unisex adulto'),
('CHO', 'Chicos'),
('CHA', 'Chicas'),
('UXI', 'Unisex infantil'),
('BEB', 'bebes'),
)
tallas = (
('EC', 'XS'),
('CH', 'S'),
('MD', 'M'),
('GD', 'L'),
('EG', 'XL'),
('SG', 'XXL'),
)
autor=models.CharField(max_length=25)
estado = models.CharField(
    max_length=2,
    choices=estados,
    default='EC',
)
genero = models.CharField(
    max_length=3,
    choices=generos,
    default='UXA',
)
prenda = models.CharField(
    max_length=2,
    choices=prendas,
    default='TP',
)
talla = models.CharField(
    max_length=2,
    choices=tallas,
    default='CH',
)
direccion = models.CharField(max_length=500)
/*if i comment this line imagen work fine*/
imagen = models.ImageField(null = False,blank=False)
descrip = models.TextField()

def __str__(self):
    return '{}'.format(self.autor)
```

Comment: Did you include `enctype` attribute in the html form as multipart; `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?

Comment: You have two things called `donacion_Form`, which is not a good idea.

Comment: Without the exact error message (whether it's a form validation error or an exception), it will be difficult to tell what goes wrong. As Borut mentions, you need the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your html `<form>` tag, but that's not the only thing that might go wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
imagen = models.ImageField(null = False,blank=False， upload_to='imagen/')
```

Specify upload directory with `upload_to`，more info [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/01/how-to-upload-files-with-django.html).

```
class DonacionCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name='App/donacion.html'
    form_class = DonacionForm
    success_url=reverse_lazy('mi_donacion')

class DonacionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=donacion
        fields="__all__"


<form class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data"
      action="{% url 'donacion_create' %}"
      method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.media }}
    {{ form.errors}}
    {{form}}

    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Create"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Add form.errors to html,see if any error occur.
If still wrong,please update the phenomenon and error message.

Comment: didnt work, the line create carpet call image but not save anyting to database or the image in the path. im thinking im doing wrong something but i dont know what

Comment: Without more detail no one can help.Can't create instance or create instance with blank imagen?

Comment: While specifying an `upload_to` path is indeed a good idea, this won't solve the problem obviously.